# php wrong timezone issue in Australia/Sydney

Tags: php, timezone

I want to get Timezone name in Australia/Sydney (not a time)

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php (timezone set)

```
$t = new DateTime('now'); 
$t->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
echo $t->format("Y D M j H:i T");
```

And result = 2014 Tue Dec 16 17:54 EST

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aedt

In this URL, Australia/Sydney is AEDT.
Why php return EST?

Comment: are you trying this code in your local ?

Comment: In my server. php info : System Linux servername 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 14:58:14 EDT 2010 x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2014-August/000023.html

[Australia DST timezone abbreviation incorrect when using date_default_timezone_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198664/australia-dst-timezone-abbreviation-incorrect-when-using-date-default-timezone-s)

It was version issue.

Comment: You can find the latest versions for PHP here: http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Answer (score 2):

Hope this work for you

```
$test = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');
$gmt = new DateTimeZone('AEDT');

$date = new DateTime('2011-12-25 00:00:00', $test);
$date->setTimezone($gmt);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I want to see whether the Sydney now daylight saving time in the time zone display. And I think i find the answer -> http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2014-August/000023.html