# PHP - get time zone abbreviation including daytime saving

Tags: php

***PHP***

```
$city = "Australia/NSW";
function get_timezone_abre()
{   
    global $city;
    $dateTime = new DateTime(); 
    $dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($city )); 
    return 'A'.$dateTime->format('T'); 
}
```

***Result***

```
AEST
```

Not sure either this will show daylight saving has started, can someone clarify this please?

Looked at this link, [what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations).

Can someone suggest a better way to do this (includes daylight saving)?

**Add reading material**

[Australia DST timezone abbreviation incorrect when using date_default_timezone_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198664/australia-dst-timezone-abbreviation-incorrect-when-using-date-default-timezone-s)

- Base on this, I assume my abbreviation `EST` is derived from using older php lib.

Comment: What's with the `A` at the start? If you're getting just `EST` as your timezone then it's not using the `Australia/NSW` timezone but rather some north american timezone (Eastern Standard Time). You should get either `AEST` or `AEDT` where one is standard time and the other is daylight time

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736789/php-datetime-dst

Comment: As well why are you doing a global here? Shouldn't you pass in the timezone instead? If you want it to ALWAYS be `Australia/NSW` by default then you should either update your php.ini to set a default timezone, or add `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/NSW');` as the first line in your code if editing the php.ini isn't possible or undesired.

Comment: @Augwa What can I use to find why it doesn't use `AEST` or `AEDT`? Use of `global` is a habit dies hard haha, and also I have no idea where it is declared.

Comment: probably because $city is something else. using globals reduces the predictability of your code. What does `$dateTime->format('e');` return? Probably `America/New_York` or some other EST timezone is my guess.

Comment: @Augwa `echo $dateTime->format('e');`, i get `Australia/NSW`.

Comment: Then your output should be giving you `AAEST` then, not `AEST`

Comment: without the string `'A'`, my output is `EST`. I tried `$city = America/new_york;`, what I got is `EDT` and I assumed it is `EST` in winter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Australia/NSW is not a valid timezone identifier. Valid timezone identifiers for Australia are:</s>

```
[299] => Australia/Adelaide
[300] => Australia/Brisbane
[301] => Australia/Broken_Hill
[302] => Australia/Currie
[303] => Australia/Darwin
[304] => Australia/Eucla
[305] => Australia/Hobart
[306] => Australia/Lindeman
[307] => Australia/Lord_Howe
[308] => Australia/Melbourne
[309] => Australia/Perth
[310] => Australia/Sydney
```

You can find this list by using `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` (see [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)).

`Australia/NSW` is valid but this comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php#119198) says it was included for backwards compatibility and could be removed.

This code should do what you need, it considers the daylight savings changes too:

```
<?php
$city = "Australia/NSW";
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($city);
$date_time = new DateTime('now', $timezone);

echo $date_time->format('T') . PHP_EOL;
echo $date_time->modify('+6 months')->format('T');
```

This will output:

```
AEST
AEDT
```

Demo here: https://eval.in/772564

Comment: i tried to set the default time zone to `Australia/NSW`, but still the output for city is `EST`.

Comment: Converting timezones is much more complicated than this.  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
echo date_default_timezone_get(); // Europe/Sofia
echo ' => '.date('T'); // => EET
```